# How to make Julia's Weave package properly handle multiple plots in a document?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I am trying to generate simple documents using [Weave](https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl/tree/master).  I have a Julia script in a `.jl` file.  Verbiage is in comments, code is on its own lines.

I am using the Plots package with GR or PyPlots.  I generate two plots.  The code for these two plots is separated by text blocks.  Looks something like this:

```
using Plots

#' Paragraph 1
plot( randn(16) )
hline!( [0] )

#' Paragraph 2
plot( rand(32) )
hline!( [0,1] )
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get the paragraphs, I get the code snippets, and I get 2 plot figures but both the plot figures are the same plot: the last one.  I've tried adding `#+` lines to separate the code chunks, I've tried adding the `term=true` option, I've tried `reuse=false` for the plot commands, still the same repeated plot.  With the `term=true` option it actually creates 3 plots and they are in the wrong order.

How do I properly handle multiple plot figures in a Weave script?

**More system info**:  Running on a mac.  Julia version 1.9.0 and Weave 0.10.12.  This happens both when running in VSCode (I don't use the plot pane) and in a Julia REPL that runs by itself in a terminal.

Comment: Hadn't used Weave before but just tried to replicate this issue and it works fine on my machine. I'm using Julia 1.8.5 and 0.10.12 for Weave. I put your code in a .jl script and then told Weave to make a PDF and it spits out exactly what you described you wanted! I didn't invoke any extra options, just simply did `weave(fname,out_path=out,doctype="md2pdf")`. It outputs correctly for me either as HTML or as a PDF via LaTeX -- does it produce the same incorrect behavior for you regardless of output format?

Comment: @kirklong I'm using Julia 1.9 Weave 0.10.12.  Now it hangs on `Weaving chunk 2` so I can't really check.  I mostly tried to get it to do PDFs.  I have pretty much given up on this and now I'm using the Jupyter plugin for VSCode.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of the latest Julia (1.9.2) with the latest Weave (0.10.12) and again see no issue...mine outputs correctly. I might suggest running a new instance of julia (i.e. just download the latest version and run it from bin there) and installing just Weave and Plots, then trying your example, to see if it works? 

Alternatively if you've given up and don't care to debug further then can you close the question?

Comment: @kirklong "Given up" might be too strong.  "Resigned to" is probably more accurate.  I would still like to know the answer, especially since the jupiter vscode plugin doesn't publish to a document without python.

Comment: then you need to provide more information so someone can recreate your problem...right now as is things are working fine so need more info on your setup to understand what's not working

Comment: @aquaticapetheory: for the hanging on problem, see: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/weave-hangs-when-trying-to-generate-a-plot/80617/3?u=czylabsonasa

Previously (on, linux) had the same problem and setting the ENV["GKSwstype"] solved the problem.